# java command line to execute eclipse project with package and jar to import

Tags: java, command-line

I have a project, in Eclipse, and I try to write the command line to run in outside of eclipse (it works in eclipse well).
the project is cut between different packages and sub packages, so I have difficulties with the classpath.

from the main directory, I have a folder for tests(where I need to get an argument), and a /bin folder with my packages and .class.
I also need to add a .jar found in /bin.

in the /bin,I have different packages, such as compiler (contains Main.class and main method),
other simple packages (for example visitor), or packages including more packages (for example : a common package containing a .class and two sub packages).

I tried `java -cp bin/compiler:bin/myjar.jar Main tests/mytest`

but I systematically get an `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main (wrong name: compiler/Main)`error.
I thought of including the .classpath of eclipse, but had no idea of how to do it.

thank you for your answer,

Comment: I'll try not to go into why you want to do this :-). The class Main is in the default package?

Comment: class Main in compiler package. and it's for an assignment, where teachers refuses to run using eclipse...

Comment: Try with java -classpath bin/compiler:bin/myjar.jar compiler/Main tests/mytest

Comment: "cannot found principal class compiler.main"